# Open a pop up when you click a 3 dot button beside a text box to search something in pop up. click one of the returned data in search to fill text box

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Hi I may have to improve how i ask this question but i will try my best on first go. I want to have text box with like a ... button beside it. When user clicks 3 dot button it should open up a pop up. In pop up i will have search box. if you type something in search box and click search button in pop up it will trigger an api call which will return data to be displayed in pop up in some angular tabular form. we use ag-grid in our project to display stuff like this.

for pop up i looked at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/overlaypanel but not exactly fits this purpose i think. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you stuck on any code?

Comment: So the question was not clear. sorry about that. i guess my question was what to use as pop up to achieve scenario i described?

Comment: The most popular "pop up" are from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) or [material-angular](https://material.angular.io/). Don't forget others like [prime-ng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) or [nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/). So, if you don't want create yourself a popUp -it's not difficult- choose **one** of this libraries and use the popup and the tables that offer. NOTE: I can not suggest one, it's your team who have to choose one.

Comment: A pop up can be just a `<div>` with `position:absolute` overlayed over your page, preferably with another screen-filling `<div>` below it that obscures the underlying website.